# User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, passport-local-mongoose

I'm trying to register users and then authenticate them using passport-local-mongoose. When I try to register a user I get the error 'User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required.' I got rid of the error by changing `required` to `false` for `password` field of my userSchema in 'userModel.js' but I assume that password has to be required. Does anyone know of a better solution?
And moreover I don't understand why it's giving me the error when I've included a password field for the user.

And when I do change `required` to `false` for `password`, the registration works and I end up with the user stored in the Users collection, but then the authentication gives me a Status 400 Bad Request error and over there I'm completely stuck.

This is my server.js

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import userRouter from "./routers/userRouter.js";
import session from "express-session";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import passport from "passport";

import User from "./models/userModel.js";

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(session({
  secret: "some secret sentence",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || "mongodb://localhost/somedatabase", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
});
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use("/api/users", userRouter);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Server is ready");
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
});
app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Serve at http://localhost:5000");
});
```

userRouter.js:

```
import express from "express";
import expressAsyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import User from "../models/userModel.js";
import passport from "passport";
import passportLocalMongoose from "passport-local-mongoose";

userRouter.post("/register", expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) =>{
    const createdUser = new User({name: req.body.name, username: req.body.email})
    User.register(createdUser, req.body.password, async function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/register");
        }else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req ,res , function(){
                    console.log("authenticate successful");
                    res.send({
                    _id: createdUser._id,
                    user: createdUser.name,
                    email: createdUser.username,
                    isAdmin: createdUser.isAdmin,
                    token: generateToken(user)
            })
        })
    }
})
```

userModel.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import passport from "passport";
import passportLocalMongoose from "passport-local-mongoose";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        password: {type: String, required: true},
        isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false, required: true},
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
export default User;
```

RegisterScreen.jsx

```
import React,{ useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { register } from "../actions/userActions.js"

export default function RegisterScreen(props){
    const[email,setEmail] = useState("");
    const[name,setName] = useState("");
    const[password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const[confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");
    const redirect = props.location.search? props.location.search.split("=")[1] : "/";
    const userRegister = useSelector((state) => state.userRegister);
    const  {userInfo , loading, error} = userRegister;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const submitHandler = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();//prevents refresh
        if(password !== confirmPassword){
            alert("Password and confirm password do not match")
        }else{
            dispatch(register(name, email, password));
        }
    };
    useEffect(() =>{
        if(userInfo){
            props.history.push(redirect);
        }
    }, [userInfo, redirect, props.history]);
    return (
        <div className="container mt-5">
             <h1>Register</h1>
             {
                loading && <h2>Loading</h2>
             }
             {  error && <h1>{error}</h1>}
             <div className="row">
               <div className="col-sm-8">
                 <div className="card">
                   <div className="card-body">
                     <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                     <div className="form-group">
                         <label htmlFor="email">Name</label>
                         <input 
                            type="text" 
                            id="name" 
                            className="form-control" 
                            placeholder="Enter name"
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                         ></input>
                       </div>
                       <div className="form-group">
                         <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                         <input 
                            type="email" 
                            id="email" 
                            className="form-control" 
                            placeholder="Enter email"
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                         ></input>
                       </div>
                       <div className="form-group">
                         <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                         <input 
                            type="password" 
                            id="password" 
                            placeholder="Enter password"
                            className="form-control" 
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                         ></input>
                       </div>
                       <div className="form-group">
                         <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                         <input 
                            type="password" 
                            id="confirmPassword" 
                            placeholder="Enter password"
                            className="form-control" 
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
                         ></input>
                       </div>
                       <button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark">Register</button>
                       <div>
                       Already have an account? {' '}
                       <Link to={`/login?redirect=${redirect}`}>Log into your account</Link>
                       </div>
                     </form>

                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>

               <div className="col-sm-4">
                 <div className="card">
                   <div className="card-body">
                     <a className="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google" href="/auth/google" role="button">
                       <i className="fab fa-google"></i>
                       Sign In with Google
                     </a>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>

             </div>
            </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `password` field from the model. Passport takes care of that